# How does assigning string literals to char[] work?

Tags: c

The C book I'm working through says that string literals are constants, but when I assign them to character arrays, individual characters can be assigned new values. Are the string literals converted into something else during assignment? Are they not inherently constant?

Reading through some other StackOverflow answers, some say that this should result in errors, so I can't figure out why it's working.

Running

```c
char string[12] = "hello world";
string[5] = '-';
printf(string);
```

Prints `hello-world`.

Running

```c
"hello world"[5] = '-';
```

Results in an error `error: assignment of read-only location ‘"hello world"[5]’` during compilation.

Comment: These are initializations, not assignments. An initialization specifies the value of an object when it is defined. They appear only in declarations. An assignment stores a value in an object. They appear in expression statements. `char string[12]` declares an array of 12 `char`. That array is not a string literal. It is given its initial value from the string literal when it is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, a string literal is stored in read-only memory; but, when you initialize a string literal to a character array, as in your first example, it gets copied into the character array, which is *not* in read-only memory. It is the character array that can be modified; not the literal itself.

Comment: Is there a way to store a string literal in a variable without copying it into a character array?

Comment: When compiled it ends up in a read-only data segment, so no, you *must* copy it to make it mutable. If you want it read-only, then you can just use a pointer to it, no copy required. `char* string = "..."`.

Comment: It's immutable by default. That means you can't mutate it.

Comment: @NoamEyal: There is no meaning to storing a string literal in a variable without copying it into a character array. Every “variable” in C is an identifier (name) and an object (a region of memory that holds its value). The only sense in which a string literal can be stored in an object is to put the characters of the string into the object, which means the object must be an array of characters (although you can abuse other types of objects and treat them as arrays of characters, but that is another topic). So your question asks to have a string in an object without having it in the object.

Comment: There is no assignment taking place in OP's code, and you cannot assign to an array. I suspect OP also has some confusion about arrays and pointers (thinking they're the same thing), and this answer does nothing to dispell that.